# In kernel module, how to know whether given path is file or directory?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel-module

In a kernel module, I have a path, say */tmp/foo*, how can I know whether it is directory or a file?

Comment: I think of kernel space as a protected portion of RAM (or virtual memory), and not directly related to the file system.  Your question seems to tie these together.  Please edit your question to be much more clear.

Comment: That's not what he means -- he means "what C code can I execute in the kernel, which will tell me if that file exists and is a directory?"

Answer (score 3):

I found a macro called **S_ISDIR()** which can be used to know whether given path is a file or directory. To use this macro, we need *inode*, which can be obtained from *struct path*, as follows:

```
        struct path path;
        int error;
        struct inode *inode;
        error=kern_path(filename,LOOKUP_FOLLOW, &path);
        if(error)
        {
                printk(KERN_INFO "error");
        }
        inode = path.dentry->d_inode;
        printk(" inode :%lu\n inode mode %u", inode->i_ino, inode->i_mode);
        if(S_ISDIR(inode->i_mode))
        {
                printk(KERN_INFO "It is a directory!");
        }
        else
        {
                printk(KERN_INFO "It is a file!");
        }
```

Comment: In the case of error that is file does not exist, you bursted kernel. (`Unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference at virtual address`)